# Compare a selected list view item with a font style

Tags: c#, listview, fonts, sms

I have a listview that behaves like a inbox. Unread messages are displayed in bold font and read messages are shown in regular font. I am able to display this way but when user clicks on a unread message, the font should change to regular since it is read now. I am trying to do it this way but does not work.

```
   private void lvwMessages_MouseDoubleClick_1(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
            ListViewItem item = lvwMessages.SelectedItems;
            if(item.Font = Font.Bold)

                {
                    item.Font = new Font(item.Font, FontStyle.Regular);
                }
    }
```

Correct procedure please

Comment: See the "s" on SelectedItem**s**? That should tell you something...

Comment: Well from the method name, I am guessing you are adding a double click handler, but you want the click handler for this. Also, you should be using `==` in your if statement, not `=`

Comment: Also, `Font.Bold` does not exist. [`Bold` is a boolean property of `Font`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.font.bold.aspx), so you want to be testing `item.Font.Bold`...

Comment: @ lc : there is only SelectedItems property, no SelectedItem for a listview. Did I get you right or you are telling me anything else?

Comment: @ Ic: item.Font.Bold is still a bool property

Comment: @Cdeez That is correct, and that should tell you something. Take a close look at your errors and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selecteditems.aspx - `SelectedItems` returns a `System.Windows.Forms.ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection`, not a single `ListViewItem`

Comment: @pstrjds yes I changed it to '==' but this is the error-`Error 2 Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Drawing.Font' and 'bool'` 
`

Comment: @Cdeez But you're comparing a `Font` object to "`Font.Bold`"...`Font.Bold` doesn't mean what you think it is. Whatever class this is in (probably a form) has a `Font` property, so `item.Font = Font.Bold` is actually doing `item.Font = this.Font.Bold`!

Comment: @ic In that case ill use SelectedItems[0], which will give me a single selected item right?

Comment: @Cdeez It will give you the *first* selected item, yes. Again, read the compiler's errors. They help, I promise.

Comment: @ IC: thanks that gave me some idea. Solved my problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Ic. This is the solution:

```
            ListViewItem item = lvwMessages.SelectedItems[0];
            if(item.Font.Bold)

                {
                    lvwMessages.SelectedItems[0].Font = new Font(lvwMessages.Font, FontStyle.Regular);
                }
```